# Следует ли закрывать вопросы с не этичными или противозаконными запросами?

Tags: обсуждение

Периодически вижу вопросы вида "как взломать" или "как сделать" что-то не законное или же на мой взгляд не этичное по отношению к пользователям сервиса.
Например [в вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/774702/%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BF%D1%83-%D0%B2%D0%BA) автор спрашивает, как сделать автоподписку на группу в ВК у посетителей его сайта. Обычно, когда я вижу такой вопрос я его просто минусу, а если в очереди проверок, то пропускаю. 
Возможно такие вопросы следует закрывать с какой то особенной причиной?

Comment: К сожалению, сообщество решило не закрывать неэтичные вопросы и вопросы о причинении вреда другим. Просто ставьте минус.