# Ограничить закрытие вопросов как дубликатов на Мете

Tags: обсуждение, закрытие-вопросов, мета, дубликаты

Коллеги, меня волнует следующий вопрос.

Как мы все знаем, наше сообщество самоуправляемое, и решения принимаются здесь, на Мете. Когда мнение сообщества меняется, возникает новый вопрос на Мете, голосование в котором отменяет старые решения, и новое решение становится законом.

Однако, не должны ли мы в этом случае пересмотреть практику закрытия вопросов на Мете как дубликатов? Ведь этим мы препятствуем изменению ранее принятого решения, и однажды принятое решение, которое более не соответствует позиции сообщества, остаётся действующим навсегда.

Возможно, имеет смысл запретить объявлять вопросы дубликатами к слишком старым вопросам (например, старше полугода), чтобы сообщество имело шанс изменить устаревшее решение.

Comment: Так вопросы не всегда предлагают что-то изменить.

Comment: @Nofate: Хорошо, в этом случае ограничивать не нужно.

Comment: @Nofate: Хотя, вот [этот вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6785/10105) можно считать предложением об изменении? Его так быстро закрыли, а вдруг консенсус уже поменялся?

Comment: Неплохо было бы добавить ссылку на "решения принимаются здесь, на Мете. .. голосование в котором отменяет старые решения, и новое решение становится законом.". Т.к. как все мы знаем, не все знают о легитимности решений на Мете.

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan: Если вы найдёте, добавьте, пожалуйста!

Comment: Кажется первый абзац можно грохнуть как "приветствие". Ведь этот подход мы ещё не пересмотрели :)

Comment: @VladD автор спрашивает, что делать в ситуации Х. Это отличный кандидат для закрытия дубликатом, раз у нас есть готовое решение.

Comment: Если бы он написал, что-то в духе "У нас есть общепринятая практика X (ссылка), но я считаю, что ее стоит пересмотреть, вот список причин, вот список примеров", то это был бы уже другой вопрос.

Comment: @Nofate: Этим мы ограничиваем новичков. Как новичку догадаться, какие именно заклинания нужно произнести, чтобы вопрос не был закрыт?

Comment: @VladD для начала новичок должен быть действительно новичком. Хотя, учитывая, высказанное как-то замечание про "language-lawyer` на Мете, к новичкам можно отнести ~99% участников, и это из числа **активных**.

Comment: @VladD после закрытого дубликата, новичек поймет, что такая проблема уже обсуждалась. И если он все еще будет уверен, что надо что-то менять, то создаст новый вопрос (скорее всего с текстом "это не дубликат, а отдельный вопрос").

Comment: @Nofate: То есть мы отсеиваем авторов инициатив по критерию "настойчивость"? Какой смысл этого?

Comment: @VladD при чем тут настойчивость?

Comment: @Nofate ...при том, что первый вопрос завернут - только настройчивый будет заходить на второй круг.

Comment: На самом деле вся система вопрос-ответная не подходит для принятия решений. Нахлабучками этого не исправить. Мне кажется тут нужно что-то типа гитхаб-вики с версями, пулреквестами и голосованием. И еще про арбитраж мечтается.

Comment: Пол года скорее всего маловато будет, а вот те вопросы которые лежат где-то в глубине с древним возрастом более 2-х или ещё больше лет, то возможно..

Answer (score 5):

Есть вопросы–дубликаты, а есть вопросы–инициативы. Если из текста вопроса видно, что автор не знает о существовании другого вопроса–аналога, то мы его закрывает как дубликат. С вопросами инициативами дело обстоит по другому. Как именно — зависит от контекста. Ясно одно, что если мы хотим пересмотреть какое–то решение, просто похожего вопроса недостаточно. Необходимо детально рассмотреть проблему, текущее решение и почему оно более не не решает проблему в текущем окружении. Если автор вопроса–инициативы хочет предложить новое решение, его следует разместить ответом к вопросу, чтобы оно участвовало в голосовании на равне с остальными предложениями.

Как вы видите, вопрос–инициатива кардинально отличается от дубликата. Спутать их сложно. Если путаница возникает, то скорее всего это дубликат, а не инициатива. Я еще не видел, чтобы инициативу (с подробным рассмотрением какой–либо проблемы в данный момент) закрывали как дубликат.

Второе, на что хотелось бы обратить внимание — голоса. Представим, что какое–то решение было принято, к примеру, 40 голосами, в результате длительного и детального рассмотрения большим количеством активистов. Не хотелось бы, чтобы кто–то как–то в случайной, далеко не всем ясной форме незаметно опубликовал якобы предложение, сам на него ответил, и решением, например, 3х голосов, из которых один против, «сообщество» приняло новое решение. Как именно стоит поступать в вопросах пересмотра правил, вопрос открытый и подлежащий отдельному детальному рассмотрению. Держать в уме это стоит наряду с требованиями детального рассмотрения исходной проблемы, текущего способа решения и его изъянов в связи с изменившейся ситуацией.

Comment: "Необходимо детально рассмотреть проблему, текущее решение и почему оно более не не решает проблему в текущем окружении." -- а почему недостаточно просто "мы, сообщество, больше так не считаем"?

Comment: @VladD На мой взгляд, это как дописывать новые пункты в подписанный контракт в одностороннем порядке. Если кто–то из сообщества считает, что ранее принятое решение неверно, у него на то есть причины. Более того, обычно мы предполагаем дискуссию. Если мнение сообщества меняется, для тех, кто высказывает свою позицию хотелось бы как–то об этом знать. И, при необходимости, пояснить или уточнить позицию, чтобы убедить коллег в правильности решения. Если мы говорим – «хорошо, мы приняли решение», многие участники более не обсуждают проблему и считают некоторое состояние зафиксированным.

Comment: То есть, если вот решение было принято обсуждением и голосами, что изменилось, что «мы, сообщество, больше так не считаем»? Поменялись либо обстоятельства, либо само сообщество. Это и следует пояснить, на мой взгляд!

Comment: Не вполне понимаю, почему голосования недостаточно? Зачем сообщество должно объяснять свои решения и кому? Если раньше решение было принятно с 20 голосами за, а сейчас в новом голосовании 25 голосов против, чего ещё не хватает?

Comment: @VladD Смотрите. Скажем, некая группа людей создает правило, что надо ездить по правой стороне дороги. Мы все десятилетиям так делаем. Далее, кто–то без объяснений говорит, что с этого момента мы ездим по левой стороне дороге, причем не публично говорит, а просто тихо–мирно выпускает новый буклет с правилами, по которому учатся новички.

Comment: @VladD Подскажите, пожалуйста, как вы предлагаете отслеживать набор существующих решений? Кто ответственен за совершение необходимых изменений, если решение изменится (кому следует переделывать все)? А если решение будет меняться каждые три месяца, следует ли всю базу «перелопачивать» каждый раз? Если нет, то зачем вообще нужно решение, которе на половину реализовано?

Comment: Мы открыто обсуждаем проблемы, для того чтобы принять наиболее верное решение. Если в ответах на Мете присутствуют все доводы (они же гипотезы), мы всегда можем посмотреть, что действительно верно, а что — заблуждение и имея эти данные как–то двигаться дальше по более оптимальному пути, чем был предыдущий шаг. Если мы будем менять правила ни с того, ни с сего, мы не сможем контролировать «прогресс». Это будут просто случайные судороги.

Comment: Нет, аналогия не такая. Новый буклет правил, как и старый, проходит голосование. И только если сообщество его примет, старые правила будут отменены. И разумеется, новый буклет не может быть принят двумя голосами.

Comment: Отслеживать решения — точно так же, как и сейчас, не вижу разницы. Если новые принятые правила частично или полностью отменяют старые, то в вопросе, в котором обсуждались старые правила, нужно оставить ссылку на новые правила.

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю фразу «что действительно верно, а что — заблуждение». Единственным источником власти и критерием истинности является Мета, правильно? Поэтому верно то, за что проголосовали мы, участники. А то, против чего мы проголосовали — неверно. Контролировать прогресс не нужно (да и кто должен его контролировать?)

Comment: Чтобы новый буклет прошел голосование, его надо выставить на голосование, а это и есть вопрос–инициатива! :) «что действительно верно, а что — заблуждение» — имеется в виду, мы все можем заблуждаться по какому–то поводу все вместе (большинством голосов), но проведя тестирование мы можем выяснить эмпирическим путем, так оно или нет. Для этого нужно зафиксировать плавила и, следовательно, голосование в них.

Comment: «Контролировать прогресс не нужно» — мне кажется, мы допускаем очень серьезную ошибку, мы обсуждаем какие–то абстрактные абстракции. Что–то, да, не нужно. А что–то — нужно. Например, мне бы крайне хотелось, чтобы вопросы закрывались правильно. Следовательно, надо учитывать не только проблему закрытия как–таковую, но и смотреть как очередная формулировка справляется с задачей по сравнению с предыдущей. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как проверить какое решение действительно верное не производя численные измерения?

Comment: *"Если путаница возникает, то скорее всего это дубликат, а не инициатива. Я еще не видел, чтобы инициативу (с подробным рассмотрением какой–либо проблемы в данный момент) закрывали как дубликат."* - я пару раз видел, но случаев не вспомню уже.

Comment: @VladD Как результат нашей дискуссии написал вопрос отдельный вопрос: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6835/

Answer (score 5):

1. В старых вопросах тоже можно голосовать.
2. Если есть какие-то причины для пересмотра, то их обычно пишут прямо в вопросе, соответственно, вопрос не закрывается как дубликат.
3. Связи с дубликатами важны в плане единой точки с решением.

Т. о. надо просто понимать, появились ли новые факты, из-за которых следует обсуждать вопрос повторно, либо же спрашивающий просто не в курсе о принятом решении и его надо закрыть как дубликат.

Comment: На мой взгляд, в старых вопроса все–таки лучше не голосовать. С какого–то момента мы начали использовать историческую блокировку именно из за голосов, которые поступали после принятия решения (и не всегда в его пользу!)

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, а что в этом плохого? Как раз будет видно, что может быть стоит изменить решение.

Comment: Плохо то, что обычно мы ссылаемся на обсуждение и говорим что–то вроде «большинством голосов сообщество решило то–то». Человек заходит, а там совсем не большинство, и вообще, вроде как за другое решение все голосовали, и, как результат, начинает поступать обратным от принятого решения образом. Так, например, было с множественным/единственным числом меток. Начали подчищать, а через год ситуация изменилась и часть сообщества начало назначать синонимы в обратном направлении. Результат — анархия. И ничего не докажешь же потом!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, ну так это как раз ситуация, что мнение изменилось. Мы посылаем в тему с решением, он её читает и голосует. Если многие голосуют за другое решение, значит позиция сообщества изменилась, нет?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, а ещё тут есть принятые ответы.

Comment: Проблема в том, что большинство людей, кто принимал участие уверены в одном решение, но оно «якобы» уже не верно. Подскажите, как они должны узнать, что ситуация изменилась, и, что самое важное, почему она изменилась?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, запустить новое обсуждение по типу "было принято решение такое-то, но судя по голосам его пора изменить".

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, хотя хм.. Несколько неправильная позиция про изменение позиции, потому что в тему будут посылать тех, кто сделал по-другому, поэтому возрастает вероятность голосов именно против.

Comment: Тоже прекрасный аргумент «против» голосования после принятия решения.

Comment: *"Связи с дубликатами важны в плане единой точки с решением."* - достаточно и простой ссылки же

Comment: @PavelMayorov, 10 связанных вопросов про одно и то же, с разными обсуждениями. А где принятые решения искать, если всё открыто и шевелится?

Comment: @Qwertiy по дате. Напомню, рядом предлагается утвержденные решения держать под исторической блокировкой, так что шевелиться может только последнее.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, историческая блокировка тут вроде не обсуждается. К тому же, даты в списке связанных вопросов не показываются.

Answer (score 0):

> Однако, не должны ли мы в этом случае пересмотреть практику закрытия
> вопросов на Мете как дубликатов? Ведь этим мы препятствуем изменению
> ранее принятого решения, и однажды принятое решение, которое более не
> соответствует позиции сообщества, остаётся действующим навсегда.

Абсолютно верно, прогресс идет, мнения меняются. Нужно все таки ПЕРЕспрашивать разрешить.

> Возможно, имеет смысл запретить объявлять вопросы дубликатами к
> слишком старым вопросам (например, старше полугода), чтобы сообщество
> имело шанс изменить устаревшее решение.

Хорошая идея поставить срок, ведь полгода это не старое, а 2018 и 2023 это уже в первый класс пошел и научился писать новый человек...

Comment: Со времени, когда был задан вопрос, утекло много воды, и сообществу было отказано в самоуправляемости. Можно считать вопрос устаревшим и не имеющим отношения к текущей реальности.

Comment: (Минус не мой.)

Comment: @VladD круг замкнутый https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/13130/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b5-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f это дубликат закрой рот, тут не отвечай не актуально

Comment: ...и что теперь как же быть то

Comment: а еще странно, что за вопрос со вчерашнего дня проголосовали +1, а ответ заминусовали. Я уже оставила этот момент, что тут минусуют просто так, но подмечаю специально, потому что постепенно, те, кто имеют свое мнение будут говорить. Поколение изменится, хотят этого или нет старички. И тема станет актуальна снова, и изменят правила. Сайт не собственность, а мнение большинства. Я лично, не из обид, или привлечения внимания открываю темы, Я знаю точно, что это актуально и рано или поздно поднимется и станет ребром.

Comment: это характерно людям, говорить,..ну раз нам когда то отказали, то тема не актуальна....тут было раньше интересно, сейчас тут делать нечего. у каждого человека есть своя жизнь, а у каждой вещи (сайта) есть новые пользователи и хозяева. И если когда то отказали, совсем не значит, что откажут и сейчас. И если для вас тема не имеет отношения к вашей текущей реальности, тоже никоем образом не значит, что реальность для всех одна. Примите мои слова не как критику, или еще в каком-то контексте негативном. А просто поймите, то, от чего вы ушли/отказались когда то, сейчас занимают/любят/оживляют другие

Comment: Ну, если вы считаете, что вам-то удастся построить здесь гражданское общество, дерзайте. Я бы на вашем месте создал новый вопрос, и в нём отдельно сослался на старый, и подробно объяснил бы, почему новый не является дубликатом. Но это вам решать, я могу лишь советовать.

Comment: Нет гражданского общества, есть участники. Есть мнение большинства. Есть возможность ответить в вопросе, по которому сослались нынешние модераторы как дубликат. Когда мы отвечаем на вопрос десятилетней давности, это не говорит о том, что вопрос не имеет отношения 'к текущей реальности'  Если вопросы закрывают, зачем превращать это в бардак и спор, открывая новые и новые...я не бунтарь, я высказываю свою точку зрения, используя старую информацию вопрос который и сегодня актуален, (вашего вопроса), легче ответить на старый вопрос по-моему

Comment: ...и к тому же зная, что на сайте мало народу, пока что лучше 'поднять' старый вопрос, нежели создать новый и тем самым споры и лишнюю суету(один админ говорит, что надо новые создавать, другой принцип ведет и находит из архива 'дубликаты'). а тут вопрос поднялся (лучше чем пылиться) и его увидят те, кто на сайте, зайдут прочтут согласятся/либо дрВариант итп итд.

Comment: Если моя старая кукла будет в руках юной девочки, я не скажу, что это зря она играет в нее, и вообще новую пусть купит...если ей нравится я порадуюсь за нее, а не вспомню, что у меня отняли куклу , чтоб я спать пошла, и у меня плохие воспоминания, и вообще вся жизнь это лишь мишура......я понимаю, что у каждого свой путь......у одного вода утекает к другим притекает

Comment: именно на этот вопрос я ответила, а на предудущий 'дубликат' даже не захотелось, тк там была агрессия, а не предложение. Ваш вопрос, словно описал мои нынешние мысли один в один, и я захотела ответить. Если вас это как то тронуло, это не было моей целью, знайте

Comment: Мнение большинства есть. Но как только оно отходит в сторону от мнения компании, толку от этого мнения становится не так уж много. Впрочем, вы увидите сами.

Comment: @VladD мнение компании тут больше некому отстаивать. КМ уже давно не КМ и даже больше не сотрудник. Текущим сотрудникам залезать сюда с переводчиком, чтобы что-то навязывать, тоже необходимости/желания нет.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Мнение компании отстаивать может и некому, но от произвола любого ⬥ (как было при ПП) никто и не спасёт. Если вдруг компания захочет протолкнуть любой CoC или там поменять лицензию на «всё принадлежит нам, хаха, лузеры», то на наши «решения» и «консенсус» никто и не взглянет. А так, политических бурь покамест нет. Гром не грянул, креститься рано.