# Как создать вопрос–инициативу?

Tags: поддержка, faq

Я хочу создать инициативу, которая улучшит сообщество. Что мне для этого следует сделать? Что необходимо учесть?

Answer (score 6):

Всегда приятно, когда то, что мы делаем, служит на пользу нам и нашим коллегам: востребованность результатов нашей деятельности — лучшее вознаграждение за любой труд. Инициативы, добавляемые в сообщество, — не исключение. Творить добро всегда приятно! Главное, чтобы добро не обернулось катастрофой. Когда вы будете выносить на рассмотрение сообществу инициативу, пожалуйста, помните про несколько простых правил, описанных ниже.

#### Не навреди

Уверен, каждый участник хочет только улучшить сайт. Самое главное в этом процессе — не навредить. Любая инициатива должна улучшать сайт, не ломая остальную «экосистему» сообщества. Публикуя описание инициативы, постарайтесь рассмотреть ее со всех сторон, особенно с тех, где она может что–то сломать.

#### Начинайте с описания проблемы

Чем проще система, тем лучше. Система, состоящая из меньшего количества компонент, имеет меньшую вероятность выйти из строя. Обычно развитие происходит путем упрощения системы, уменьшения числа компонент, а не добавлением нового.

Если мы все же хотим добавить новую компоненту в систему (например, новое правило), мы должны четко понимать, какую проблему она будет решать. Если вы предлагаете улучшение уже существующего процесса, необходимо обязательно рассмотреть исходную проблему, как существующие процессы ее решают и почему этих процессов больше недостаточно (например, дать обновление проблемы или ее более детальный разбор).

Рассмотрение исходной проблемы, ее текущего решения и новый взгляд на проблему крайне необходимы, так как сообщество — динамическая сущность. Некоторые активные участники присоединились после добавления многих нововведений, но именно текущему сообществу предстоит принимать решение. Не предполагайте, что ваши коллеги знают или помнят всю историю интересной и известной вам проблемы.

#### Не менять приоритетнее, чем менять

В контексте существующих систем отсутствие изменений всегда приоритетнее любых изменений при прочих равных. Предпосылки для внесения изменений должны быть весомыми.

Когда системы еще нет, проект только запустился, мы берем «произвольные рабочие процессы», которые, на наш взгляд, удовлетворительно решают наши проблемы. На старте проблем всегда больше, чем решений, необходимо двигаться быстро. С другой стороны, изменения существующей системы — это всегда улучшения, а это дискуссия в контексте уже существующих процессов. Создавать новое всегда проще и быстрее — просто берем первое рабочее решение. Изменять сложнее, изменения должны как–либо подтвердить свое превосходство над существующими решениями. Пожалуйста, всегда помните наше первое правило — не навреди.

#### Минимум изменений за раз

Крайне хотелось, чтобы каждой инициативе было уделено максимальное внимание со стороны сообщества. Уследить за активным обсуждением сразу нескольких инициатив не всегда возможно. Если вы хотите, чтобы ваша инициатива получила больше внимания, постарайтесь сделать так, чтобы она не пересекалась с другими активно обсуждаемыми темами на Мете.

#### Метка [важное](/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5)

Система добавляет все вопросы с меткой [важное](/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5) в боковую панель основного сайта: инициатива будет более заметной для сообщества, если получит ее. Чтобы получить метку необходимо, просто упомянуть управляющего (@NicolasChabanovsky) или кого–либо из модераторов в [общем чате сообщества](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--). Пожалуйста, помните, что модератор может отказать вам в установлении метки если одновременно рассматриваются достаточное количество вопросов с меткой [важное](/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5) или по другим причинам, к примеру, если рассматриваемый вопрос не интересен сообществу.

#### Рекомендуемое оформление: вопрос — только описание проблемы, все остальное — в ответ

Публикуя вопрос–инициативу, убедитесь, что идея самой инициативы и ваши мысли о ней разнесены в разные сообщения. Вопрос–инициатива должен содержать исключительно рассмотрение самой проблемы, то есть «сухие факты» без каких–либо эмоций или мнений автора инициативы о способах решения. Личный взгляд автора вопроса–инициативы на способы решения указанной проблемы должны быть вынесены в отдельный ответ.

Пожалуйста, обратите особое внимание на это! Если вопрос–инициатива в своей постановке содержит предвзятое мнение автора, лозунги, призывы или агитацию к конкретному способу решения, мы рискуем получить ответы только одного типа, без детального рассмотрения проблемы, а критикующие лишь сам вопрос.

Конечно, вопрос может и должен отражать неравнодушие автора и к проблеме, и к важности ее решения, но он (вопрос) должен быть абсолютно нейтрален к способам решения. Если вопрос будет содержать определенное мнение о решении, большинство ответов будут лишь противопоставлениями.

#### Право наложить вето

Управляющий сообществом может наложить вето на любой вопрос–инициативу, если он противоречит морали или миссии проекта на любой стадии. (Например, как бы не хотели участники, вопросы рукоделия не будут внесены в тематику сайта, так же как мы не будем отходить от формата вопросов и ответов в сторону дискуссионного форума.) Наложение вето должно быть подкреплено пояснением, которое однозначно дает понять, почему данное решение не получит реализацию в рамках Stack Overflow.

---

Пожалуйста, не стесняйтесь обсуждать инициативы в [общем чате сообщества](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--), где вы всегда сможете найти наиболее активных участников сообщества.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, не думаю, что старые комментарии надо удалять,  [переместил их в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73160/discussion-on-answer-by-nicolas-chabanovsky---).

Comment: Так это “Рекомендуемое оформление" или обязательное?