# Можно ли увеличить время нахождения сообщения об уходе модератора в блоке «важное на Мете» на Stack Overflow на русском (более 24 часов)?

Tags: обсуждение, инструменты-модератора, блок-важных-вопросов

На общей мете [был задан вопрос](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/342253/383809): сколько могут/должны висеть в [важное](/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5) объявления об уходе модераторов.

Сегодня, [был получен официальный ответ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342363/383809): **24 часа**.

Будет ли «правило 24 часов» применяться на Stack Overflow на русском или его можно настроить?

---

**Почему это важно**:

- 24 часа - это очень короткий срок для того чтобы охватить аудиторию.
- Применение частных правил для разных новостей затрудняет их практическое исполнение.

Кроме того, на мой взгляд, подобное выборочное применение метки, отчасти, является проявляением невнимания к модераторам, которые решили сказать "до свидания" после долгих лет службы.

**Применялось ли это уже?**

Да, но не в русском сегменте. [Недавно подобное произошло на StackOverflow на английском](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392889/2452869).

Comment: на ruso не особо много/часто модераторов отставляют

Comment: @Grundy нигде **часто** модераторов не отставляют. Именно поэтому, ограничение "важности" такого экстраординарного и, простите за тавтологию, важного события – выходит за грани моего понимания.

Comment: поправил отставку - на уход, так звучит более точно.

Comment: @AntonMenshov Опубликуйте, пожалуйста, ваши [мысли ответом](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6836/6) (все, что ниже разделителя). В текущем виде это вопрос-заявление и нам, сообществу, нечего в нем делать.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky не согласен. Это не будет никак отвечать на вопрос. Кроме того, [это нормальная практика делиться частью своих мыслей прямо в вопросе](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9704/337980)

Comment: Кроме того, я специально написал эти параграфы для раскрытия и обоснования вопроса, без них вопрос не имеет необходимой картины (для примера - смотрим контекст вопроса на Общей Мете). Это не противоречит ни одному из правил, что я знаю и какие использую при модерировании другого сообщества - Computational Science.

Comment: Вы приводите примеры совершенно несравнимые. Если бы вы добавили ваше пояснение к вопросы на MSE, то да, но не к вашему текущему вопросу здесь, так как мы не обсуждаем это правило как таковое, если я правильно понял ваш вопрос. Подскажите,  что вы хотели уточнить, самое правило или его применение на этом сайте?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Вопрос: будет ли применяться и должно ли применяться это правило на StackOverflow на русском - напрямую связаны с тем, почему важно это обсуждение. Нельзя просто сказать "вот правило" - будем или не будем его применять. Это плохая формулировка. "вот правило", "вот контекст", "вот прецедент" - обсуждаем: тут уже может получиться конструктив.

На мой взгляд, я очень четко описал что и почему есть в вопросе, как и сам вопрос.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky я бы ещё мог понять такие правки, если бы это был вопрос к [meta-tag:поддержка] с целью получить официальную позицию от CM. Но тут [meta-tag:обсуждение] (aka интересно мнение сообщества и модераторов/CM в том числе). Не понимаю, зачем так сильно обрезать вопрос.

Comment: @AntonMenshov Можно ли не следовать правилам? — Нет нельзя. В вашей формулировке вопрос — риторический, это просто высказывание. Мета — место обсуждений правил модерации и программного обеспечения сайта. Обсуждение подразумевает необходимость участия других людей. Пожалуйста, оставьте место другим для ответа.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky это ваше частное мнение. Кроме того, вы на мой вопрос ответили. Кроме того, есть конкретные случаи исключений из правил. для неанглоязычных сообществ.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky если у вас возник новый вопрос, вы можете задать его отдельным постом на мете.

Comment: Дорогие коллеги! Я предлагаю обсудить и принять правило: если автор сообщения явно протестует против правки, правка **должна быть** отменена. Никто, кроме автора сообщения, не знает лучше, какую идею хотел донести автор сообщения. Не нравится — ставьте минус, а не вандализируйте текст! (Ровно одно исключение — сообщения, грубо нарушающие правила, мат, порнуха, оскорбления.)

Comment: В данный момент название вопроса точно не отражает то, что я хотел спросить. Я войну правок устраивать не буду - ибо я следую правилам. Общение с Николаем здесь и в нескольких чатах не привело к консенсусу. По данной конкретной теме общаться далее с Николаем смысла я не вижу - irreconcilable differences. Незачем тратить его и мое время. Удалять вопрос я не хочу, так как он представляет собой важное "свидетельство". Так и живем.

Comment: @AntonMenshov: Тем более. Если между позициями участников есть неустранимые противоречия, то мнение оппонента в принципе не может отражать мнение автора. И оппоненту следует бинайсно не навязывать своё нерелевантное мнение. Иначе это не что иное, как злоупотребление властью (если оппонент наделён этой самой властью).

Comment: @VladD я на это смотрю именно таким же образом.

Comment: [Обсуждение причин и необходимости правок - новый вопрос, заданный модератором Qwertiy](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10033/337980)

Comment: Бессмылица какая-то. Я ещё подумал, что заголовок какой-то странный, и думал советовать исправить. Что такое "настроить ограничения"? Это же не какая-то опция в конфиге, это ручное вмешательство сотрудников компании: метка "важное" всегда ставилась и снималась вручную. А вот "можно ли не применять правило" полностью отражает суть вопроса. И риторического в нём ничего нет: на этом сайте всегда былаи локализованные правила; то же пресловутое правило про местоимения на этот сайт на распространяется, и это официальная позиция руководства.

Comment: @AntonMenshov, я немного поправил заголовок. Скажи, пойдёт такое или нет. Если нет, то откати)

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica отлично. новая редакция названия точно не вызывает проблем.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вероятно, недавний [ответ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/343528/260198) компании покрывает этот вопрос. Правило о 24 часах отменили, нужно соблюсти лишь 2 формальности.

1. Участник должен дать согласие на его упоминание в вопросе.
2. Сообщение не должно нести негатива.

С первым проблем явно не будет, второе и так было в правилах. Так что, в целом, ничего не поменялось по сравнению с тем, как было раньше. Но, вероятно, если уход модератора связан с действиями компании, и тот решил об этом написать в вопросе (как [это сделала Моника](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5193/20373)), то с такого вопроса метку [важное](/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5) снимут.

Есть нюансы относительно этого сообщения от компании в более широком смысле, но они вне обсуждения данного вопроса про модераторов.

Answer (score 17):

Думаю, тебе бы хотелось ответ от CM получить, но выскажусь, как модератор.

Это решение, если судить по переписке с другими модераторами и сотрудниками, исходит не от тех людей, которые управляются сообществом и, следовательно, не может расцениваться как решение на благо сообщества. Этого нету в правилах, нету в соглашении.

Модераторов выбирает сообщество, действия модераторов направлены на помощь сообществу. Я расцениваю решение компании просто как рекомендацию, и не думаю, что ему следует следовать, если оно не подкреплено интересами сообщества.