# Я не понимаю, что не так с этим сообщением

Tags: поддержка, модерация, правки

Вот [начальная версия сообщения](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/10028/1). Она была многократно отредактирована, как нарушающая правила сайта. Я не понимаю, почему и какие правила она нарушает. [История изменений](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/10028/revisions).

PS: [Этот вопрос на метамете.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/342740/309650)

Comment: [[meta-tag:драма]], [[meta-tag:SOпротивление]], [[meta-tag:модераторский-произвол]], [[meta-tag:попкорн]], [[meta-tag:всего-плохого]], [[meta-tag:дежа-вю]]

Comment: @VladD, [[tag:vladd-казм]]

Comment: Проблема, как мне кажется, в том что Anton хотел донести "горячую" новость, а Nicolas хотел её "остудить" и переделать в более нейтральный вопрос.

Comment: @KromstersayssupportMonica что в ней горячего? Обычное обсуждение.

Comment: Горячего в ней то, что "вот, смотрите, опять злой MSE обижает сообщество и вытирает об него ноги", и посты о модераторах, действительно, то появлялись, то изчезали из обсуждаемого на MSE. Окончательного решения, по видимому, так и нет. В то же время, вбрасывать это на ruSO не совсем верно, т.к. у нас этой проблемы не было и нет. Поэтому правки Николаса не лишены логики.

Comment: А к Qwertiy как обычно претензия, что дает вопросу ни о чем не говорящее название.

Comment: @KromstersayssupportMonica хм. ну проблема на RuSO появится как только кто-то из модераторов решит уйти, что не лишено логики, учитывая что а) много модераторов уходит в принципе б) один из модераторов RuSO уже ушел довольно недавно. Факт, что правоприменение этой "горячей новости" уже имеется, так что на данный момент – это решение актуальное и задействованное.

Comment: @KromstersayssupportMonica ваш комментарий отчасти (но только отчасти) правдив. Донести новость цель имелась. Однако имелся и конкретный вопрос о применении этой политики в данном конкретном сообществе. Далеко не все, что делается на англоязычных сайтах - применяется\не применяется здесь (примеров куча), как явно - так и неявно. Отсюда мой вопрос. А также - вопрошение мнения сообщества, собственно которое и будет затронуто такой политикой.

Comment: @AntonMenshov в типовом случае, уход обычного модератора событие недостойное "важности". Вот объявит сейчас Nick Volynkin что уходит с поста - никто этого и не заметит. То есть в любом случае, вопрос решается не правилами.

Comment: @KromstersayssupportMonica этот комментарий - отличный ответ на мой изначальный вопрос. Я с ним несогласен. И я также не до конца могу быть объективным в этом вопросе вообще. Именно за этим тот вопрос изначально и задавался.

Comment: @AntonMenshov Именно к этой, спокойной, форме Николас и хотел привести ваш вопрос, не так ли? Я бы на него может быть и запостил этот ответ тогда.

Comment: @KromstersayssupportMonica нет, я это вижу совсем по-другому.

Answer (score 8):

Я получил следующее сообщение от модераторов (в частности – Николая, что в письме не указано, но правки делал он, и информация о правках публичная):

> Антон, добрый день!
>
> Спешу сообщить, что я внес изменения в ваш вопрос на Мете: Можно ли
>   настроить время нахождения сообщения об уходе модератора в блоке
>   «важное на Мете» на Stack Overflow на русском?
>
> Я понимаю, что у вас есть много мыслей и чувств по поводу указанного
>   вами решения. С другой стороны, на Stack Overflow существуют
>   определенные правила о том как должен выглядеть вопрос. В двух словах:
>   максимально минимально, но достаточно для ответа. Пожалуйста,
>   постарайтесь в будущем не включать в вопрос то, что к нему не
>   относится напрямую (например, личную оценку), ведь это никак не
>   помогает разобраться в ситуации.
>
> С уважением, команда модераторов сайта «Stack Overflow на русском»

На что я ответил:

> Я **в корне и категорично** не согласен с вашим решением, но в войну правок вступать не собираюсь. Я думаю нет никакого смысла мне вам обосновывать мое несогласие – вы и сами все знаете.

В дальнейшем я тщательно перефразировал свой вопрос с целью удовлетворить требования (хотя я и не до конца понимаю зачем).

Остальное наше общение насчет корректности правок, правоприменения редактирования с резким изменением стиля и конкретных вещей в вопросах и начало "войн правок" проходило в:

- [комментариях к вышеупомянутому вопросу](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10028/337980) (публично доступно)
- [в чате StackOverflow на русском](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/53257396#53257396) (публично доступно, мало)
- в Teacher's Lounge (приватный канал, доступно только модераторам)

К сожалению, ответы Николая меня не удовлетворили и многие аспекты освещены не были. Я выразил благодарность Николаю за попытки разъяснения, и прекратил дискуссию. Не по причине своей удовлетворенности, а лишь с целью экономии времени обоих нас, ибо дискуссия была контрпродуктивна, во всяком случае для меня.

Я надеюсь Николай ответит на вопрос Qwertiy здесь, так как мои проблемы - это мои проблемы, а данный конкретный вопрос важен с точки зрения установление прецедента для модерирования и интересует уже модераторов.

NB: Я выложил сообщение модератора в публичный доступ так как согласно моему пониманию имею на это право, ибо это разглашает только мои персональные данные и претензии модератора (CM) лично ко мне.

NB2: Считаю эту информацию важной для **частичного** ответа на поставленный вопрос и представления полной картины, ибо цитату сообщения модератора имею право выложить в публичный доступ лишь я.

Comment: «Спешу сообщить» — очень узнаваемый стиль.

Comment: На Teacher's Lounge тоже мог бы ссылку добавить.

Comment: @Qwertiy там сложновато. Есть часть обсуждения с другими модераторами (раньше), есть часть обсуждения конкретно с Николаем (позже). Плюс давать ссылку на непубличный ресурс...Как-то я такого никогда не делал. Могу ткнуть таймкодами в вас внутри TL.

Comment: Давай. А вообще, комната всё равно правами доступа защищена - просто так в неё не залезешь.

Comment: [Обсуждение с другими модераторами без Николая](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8179596#8179596) и последующее [Обсуждение с Николаем](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8180136#8180136) @Qwertiy не могу пингануть внутри комнаты, прошу прощения за публикацию ссылок, которые никому кроме модераторов недоступны, хотя я бы не сказал, что там есть какая-то новизна по сравнению с публично доступными ответами. Во всяком случае, в моем прочтении.

Comment: Важно добавить, что я не в праве (и ни в коем случае не хочу) распространять информацию из приватного канала TL. Приватность TL - важное качество. Хотя в этом случае - новизна вряд ли будет открыта Qwertiy из этого источника.

Comment: @AntonMenshov вообще, итоги обсуждений подобных разглашать своими словами можно.

Comment: Задал [вопрос на метамете](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/342740/309650) - заходи. Можешь заодно подкорректировать переводы.

Comment: @Qwertiy спасибо! Проблема будет в том, что нерусскоязычные участники будут очень неохотно высказываться по этому поводу – и я их более чем понимаю.